# write a script in c++ which read a CSV file( fail to open it)

Tags: c++

i'm trying to write a script in c++ which read a CSV file so i can treat it later .i ve used fstram but the file always fail to open**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string filename = "hello.txt"; // could come from command line.

    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
       if (!fin.is_open())
       {
           cout << "Could not open file: " << filename << endl;
           return 1;
       }
       cout<<"khalil"<<endl;
       string scores[32];    


       string names[32];    
        int iter = 0;
        while (iter <= 5)
            {
                fin >> names[iter] >> scores[iter];

                cout << iter <<"\n";
                cout<<names[iter]<< "\n";
                cout<<scores[iter]<<"\n";
                iter++;
            }
          fin.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the file is not in the same directory as the process' current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a fully qualified path name, e.g.:
`string filename = "C:\\Documents\\hello.txt";`
It appears your program isn't opening the file because it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) class to do this operation.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QFile file("C\\hello.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug()<<file.errorString();
        return 0;
    }

    QStringList firstList, secondList;
    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();
        firstList.append(line.split(',')[0]);
        secondList.append(line.split(',')[1]);
    }

    qDebug()<<firstList;
    qDebug()<<secondList;
}
```